# ImageBrush (Canvas) path not working

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, imagebrush

I am working on WPF for interactive applications. When I assign image path to `ImageBrush (Canvas)` from folder included in solution, its not working, it goes to bin/debug/.. in `WPF`. But it worked perfectly, when I assign path from directory. Following is the screenshot for issue:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unRtn.png)

Following is the code snippet I have written which is not working:

```
ImageBrush myBrush = imgContent1;
myBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Informatin_Concept_100.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
canContent1Info.Background = myBrush;
```

But following code snippet work when I am assigning images from directory:

```
C = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
imgContent1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(C + "\\" + "Content1\\Default\\Informatin_Concept_100.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Can't figure out where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [WPF Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris) to load a BitmapImage from an assembly resource. The `Build Action` of the image file in your Visual Studio project must be set to `Resource`.

```
myBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Informatin_Concept_100.jpg"));
```

Comment: its still not working, it throws an error "A relative URI can not be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI ".

Comment: @Lalit So why do you create a relative URI? Do not specify the UriKind.